# Edit 100MB+ file

Tags: text-editor, editor

I have captured some traffic with Wireshark and saved the result as a file. The file has 3 sections now:

1. request headers
2. response headers
3. response body

The response body is to become an flv file, but now everything is saved as a single file. So I need a way to delete the first two sections from the file, but the problem is that the file is very big (over a thousand mega bytes). I have tried to open it with gedit, but no matter how long I wait, gedit hangs and remains unresponsive until I kill it.

What tool can I use to edit this big file easily?

Comment: Did you try with command line text editors? `nano` or `vim`?

Comment: @medigeek - I am very clumsy with command line tools, but I'd give it a shot.

Comment: This seems like a convoluted way to steal a flash video

Comment: @tgm4883 - It may *seem* so, but it's not.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour As the file is really huge, I'd have written some sort of program in C/C++ to manipulate it.. Create a program to do what you would do with the file if you were able to open the file in some texteditor. i.e. operations like Search, delete, add text etc.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour Providing you actually have the rights to download this video, why don't you tell us where it is located and perhaps there is a better way to get it?

Comment: There! Another *Inspector Javert*! @tgm4883 The original problem resulting in this question being posted has been dealt with -- in Windows and with Notepad++. If you are eager to help though, the question is still there; let us all indulge in your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if Wireshark output that I am assuming to be a pcap file can be "nicely" divided into sections like request, response and body. The file would be a sequence of packets containing everything captured from the link layer onwards each prepended by a Wireshark header. Decoding the session that contributed to the transfer of say a big video file will require analyzing headers from the network protocol stack like IP, TCP and HTTP and combining the application level payload (e.g., HTTP).

Comment: I'm giving this a +1. There should be a "Follow TCP stream" in wireshark.. or something to make things easier...